# A comma before 'and+thus'

Tags: phrases

In the following sentence, are the words 'and' & 'thus' punctuated correctly? Should there be a come before the word 'and'? I really appreciate your help.

"Vacuum packing the apple slices eliminates oxygen and thus prevents browning without altering the apple's flavor."

Comment: This is really a matter of style and preference. In this particular case, I would recommend putting a comma after 'oxygen' because you should put a comma between two independent clauses when they are joined by a conjunction such as "and", "but" etc.

Comment: That is what I initial thought, but a closer examination of the second part of the sentence shows it is not an independent clause. Right? here is the second part:    "...prevents browning without altering the apple's flavor."

Comment: I believe in this case you're in luck because most style guides recommend treating relative clauses the same way as independent clauses with respect to commas. So whether you read it as a relative clause or (as I did) an independent clause with an implied 'it' (and thus it prevents...), the punctuation is the same.

Comment: @BigLuke Which style guides are these?

Comment: The main reason I made a comment and not an answer was that I was operating from my memory of the Chicago Manual of Style, but after reading your answer I can see how the sentence could be framed as a compound predicate and not a dependent clause.

Answer (score 3):

This question neatly illustrates how careful writers consider punctation:

> **[1]** Punctuation is a matter of style, not grammar. Thus punctuation isn't so much correct or incorrect, but is rather in or out of conformance with your style guide.
>   **[1a]** The purpose of punctuation is to guide your reader to the correct parse of your text, which is necessarily linear and unidirectional, while your grammar is neither of those.
>   **[1b]** Rules are guides, not ukases. As the *Chicago Manual of Style* says about the comma, "There are a few rules governing its use that have become almost obligatory. Aside from these, the use of the comma is mainly a matter of good judgment,...."
>   **[2]** Per the above-cited manual of style, a comma should separate independent clauses joined by a conjunction (unless the clauses are short, e.g, *I laughed and I cried.*), and a comma should not separate compound predicates.

The OP's sentence is a compound predicate, essentially:

> Vacuum packing eliminates oxygen and prevents browning.

Rule **2** would seem to preclude a comma. But there's another matter to consider: without the comma a reader might be misled into thinking that the *and* might join a compound direct object of *eliminates*, leading the reader to expect something like

> Vacuum packing eliminates oxygen and ozone...

Rules **1a** and **1b** would argue that a comma would prevent an unwary reader from making that wrong preliminary syntactic choice that would require reparsing. Will this choice confuse other readers who will take the comman as a sign of an upcoming subject? There's no definitive answer to that question, which is why this is a matter of style and judgment.

If this is the OP's own text, he may re-write himself out of the problem:

> Vacuum packing the apple slices eliminates oxygen, thus preventing browning while retaining the apple's flavor.

But the OP may not have the luxury of rephrasing, and whether a rephrase improves things is again a matter of stylistic choice.